# HNQ feed refreshes too easily by pull down, while actually sweeping left and right on Android app for tablet

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

I'm using the SE app on Android and I like to browse through the hot network question feed on the top by swiping the questions to the left.

While swiping it happens far too often, that I pull down the feed a little, so a refresh is triggered and it jumps back to the first question. (I know that not releasing the finger and pulling it up again, stops the process, but I can't manage to do that always)

As just every 5th to 10th question is of interest I get easy to the 30th question or so and it is *really* annoying if the refresh happens by accident and I need to reswipe 30 questions to get to the point where I was.

Call me clumsy, but I think I'm not the only one having the problem.

Can you make it harder to trigger the refresh? Either by a confirmation dialog or by increasing the amount of down pulling required? The problem is that it refreshes even when the finger does not leave the question feed. Moving it 1cm down already triggers the refresh. If it would be 3cm, that would no happen.

Actually a dedicated refresh button would just serve as well - as I think the refresh by pull down is not used that often anyway by the users, is it?

### Screenshot

I'm talking about the feed on the screenshot on the top (Mathematics, Physics, Game Developement) which one can sweep to the left. The screenshot is from the iOS-App, but the Android App 1.0.89/1.0.95 seems similar (I still have Android 4.4 on my tablet - '12 Nexus 7).

[image: HNQ on app feed on tablet]

Comment: Not an issue I have faced myself but I really don't want a conformation dialogue every time I want to refresh. Perhaps just adding the option to disable pull down to refresh in the settings would be a better solution? If this is an issue enough users face of course.

Comment: The problem is that it refreshes even when the finger does not leave the question feed. Moving it 1cm down already triggers the refresh. If it would be 3cm...

Comment: @AndrewT. Screenshot and version number added.